# Include object tags in event message for S3 event notifications

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-event-bridge

I have a S3 bucket which sends messages to SQS via an EventBridge rule and I would like to include the S3 objects tags (for a PutObject event) in the event message using the S3 event notifications system.

However, [this link to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/notification-content-structure.html) seems to indicate that the object tags are not included in the event message.

Currently, I obtain the tags values directly in the lambda following the SQS but I am not satisfied with this method as it requires more permissions for the lambda as well a (short) code a the beginning of the lambda to extracts the wanted tags values.

Is there a way to include the tags into the event message ?

Comment: No, you have to call [GetObjectTagging](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObjectTagging.html) to get the tags associated with an object.